# Mosaico: Signup with dedicated email address

Tags: mosaico

Hello wonderful people! 
Does anyone know anything about subscribing to a mailing group with a dedicated email address? As a result you would always receive a mailing to that specific email, regardless of your contact's primary/bulk email addresses?
There is the DB field civicrm_group_contact.email_id, but it doesn't seem to be taken into account when a contact subscribes, or when the mailing is sent out...